# Запрет использования приложения на планшете

Tags: android

можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы запретить использование приложения на планшетах? Может что-нибудь в манифесте прописать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно разработчики не запрещают использовать приложение на устройствах определенного типа. Манифест Android представляет широкие возможности ограничения работы приложений по физическим и виртуальным параметрам того или иного устройства.

Например, накладывать ограничения на размер экрана:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

На наличие тех или иных "фич" в устройстве( встроенных технологий ):

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"]
  android:glEsVersion="integer" />
```

Конфигурации:

```
<uses-configuration ... />
```

И так далее.  За более подробной информацией обращайтесь на **[официальный сайт SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)**.

---

Так, например, если у пользователя устройство что-то на подобии Samsung Galaxy Note, то тут уже довольно тяжело будет определить, что у вас: 7-дюймовый планшет или же все-таки коммуникатор. Поэтому, если ограничения действительно необходимо наложить (а этого очень часто можно избежать, "включив" мозг), накладывайте из на характеристики устройства.